# Trigger Pipelines in Multiple Azure DevOps Projects from a single Repository in Github

Tags: azure, azure-devops

As the title already suggests, we're struggling to find out how we can trigger pipelines in **multiple** DevOps projects **in the same DevOps organization** from a **single GitHub repository**.

The GitHub webhooks were automatically added by DevOps when we configured our first pipeline trigger via the button that appears in the trigger tab (it says "Restore" as it doesn't find the correct webhooks in GitHub).

Steps taken / current state:

- We've connected our repository to all projects via dedicated Service Connections
- Each push to the main branch will trigger all pipelines in all projects
- When we open a PR, only the pipelines in the project where we've clicked the button "Restore" button are triggered.
- The button to auto-configure the webhooks only appears if there are no webhooks configured in Github, so we can't do this for all of our projects.
- We also can't do it manually, as we don't know the secret that is used by DevOps within the webhooks.

Any help or tip in the right direction will be immensely helpful!

Comment: may i know if the reply helps? let me know if you have any queries.

Answer (score 0):

The PR trigger works fine to multiple devops project from one github repo on my side:

[image]

To resolve the issue, please follow below items for a check:

1. Edit the pipeline for **echo DevOps project**, make sure it can **list the yaml file** content which resides on github repo. This is to ensure each github service connection works fine.
   [image]

Also make sure PR trigger is **not** overriden:

[image]

If you use classic UI editor for pipeline, steps as similar.

1. Go to **echo DevOps project** settings -> Pipelines -> Settings, **toggle off** `Limit building pull requests from forked GitHub repositories` as it could break trigger even it's not from forked repo(known issue).
   [image]
2. Use **different pipeline name** for each pipeline in different project. Rename if needed.

[image]

Then commit on github repo, create a pull request for a check.

**If the issue persists,** you can go to target github repo -> settings -> Integrations -> GitHub Apps -> Configure Azure pipeliens app to uninstall. Then  reinstall it.

[image]

Remove github service connections for each devops project.

Then edit pipeline to restore the connection, then check for the pipeline trigger gain.